# Mac Keyboard shortcut for Area Type / Auto Size to fit content in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I thought there wasa keyboard shortcut for Illustrator like there is for InDesign for fit box to content. I know the steps to do it in illustrator, I just thought there was a shortcut for it. Anyone know it?

Comment: No, there isn't. While you can use clipping paths on your images to mimic the image box in InDesign, Illustrator handles images differently. The function you are looking for doesn't exist in Illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

More of a "hybrid" keyboard shortcut, if you hold <kbd>Command</kbd> with the type tool selected, a handle with a circular node will appear on the right side of the text box. Simply **Double-click** this node and it will fit the box to the content:
[image]
**Result:**

[image]

***Note:*** The square node that appears at the bottom of the text box will resize to fit the text vertically only when double-clicked.